# каскадное обновление данных в таблице

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица продавцов:

```
CREATE TABLE merchants(
    merchant_id                         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    merchant_name                       VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL, 
    merchant_password                   VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL,
    business_number                     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

Есть таблица продуктов:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    product_id                          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    product_name                        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    store_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES merchants ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    store_name                          INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES merchants.merchant_name ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    contact_number                      INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES merchants.contact_number ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    type_location                       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES merchants.type_location ON UPDATE CASCADE                   
);
```

Как сделать чтобы в строках `store_name`, `contact_number`, `type_location` были строковые данные из таблицы `merchants` и при обновлении данных в таблице `merchants`, обновлялись строки `store_name`, `contact_number`, `type_location` и в таблице `products`?

Comment: А зачем вам в таблице `products` колонки `store_name` и т.д? Обычно в такой ситуации хранят `merchant_id` и по этому ключу достают необходимые данные запросом. Вашу задачу можно решить триггером, но это больше похоже на выстрел в ногу. У вас проблема именно в архитектуре

Comment: @Viktorov Я понял это, то есть надо мне надо `merchant_id` взять данные из таблице `products`?

Comment: Да. Считаю это лучшим решением проблемы. Иначе у вас в двух местах будет храниться куча одинаковой информации. А при изменении чего то в `merchants` придется все время менять `products`, что ну очень неудобно

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)